# read out value of protected property TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler::$historyRecords

Tags: typo3

I'm updating a TYPO3 installation from v6 to v7 and have a problem with class `TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler`

(https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_data_handling_1_1_data_handler.html).

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot access protected property
>   TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler::$historyRecords ...

caused by the following call

```
public function processCmdmap_afterFinish(&$data)
{
    $dataChanged = $data->historyRecords;
```

Can anyone tell me how in TYPO3 v7 you can get the value of historyRecords?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: There is no getter for this protected method. The better question is: why should you need it in a hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataHandler::$historyRecords` was not defined as property in TYPO3 6.2 but was implicitly set by class member access inside `DataHandler` (see [`DataHandler` of 6.2](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_6-2/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/DataHandling/DataHandler.php)). In TYPO3 7.6 the property has been declared the first time and defined to be `protected`.

The `$historyRecords` array could be seen as change pattern, containing the `oldRecord` and `newRecord` for a particular invocation of the `DataHandler`. This could be seen as contents of a `RecordDataChangedEvent` - which does not exist in that way in TYPO3, yet. The information is collected in `DataHandler::compareFieldArrayWithCurrentAndUnset()`.

To get access to the information you have three possibilities in TYPO3 7.6:

1. Overload DataHandler by XCLASSing and provide a `getHistoryRecords()` method

   - XCLASSing is basically a bad principle since you can override functionality
     that might be changed in upstream versions. In this case it would be "okay"
     since you just provide a new getter-method that did not exist before
   - find more details in the [XCLASS documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Xclasses/Index.html)
2. Use hooks to collect and determine changes on your own

   - `processDatamap_preProcessFieldArray($incomingFieldArray, $table, $id, DataHandler $dataHandler)`
   - `processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray($status, $table, $id, $fieldArray, DataHandler $dataHandler)`
   - collect differences in a singleton object comparing `$incomingFieldArray` to `$fieldArray` for a combination of `$table` and `$id`
   - this however leaves out possible version and shadowing interactions that have been applied to the field-array in between
3. Retrieve from database table `sys_history`

   - see `DataHandler::setHistory()` and do the reverse look-up
   - at the time when your `processCmdmap_afterFinish` hook is called, this data has been written already
   - look-up a combination of the following criteria from `sys_history`

     - `tstamp` equals `$GLOBALS['EXEC_TIME']`
     - `tablename` equals `$table` AND `recuid` equals `$id`
   - the field `history_data` contains then a serialized representation of `$historyRecords`

Comment: Option 1. runs really smoothly for me. https://wiki.typo3.org/XCLASS helped me, too.

I just added:

Comment: I just added a class called DataHandlerExtended:

class DataHandlerExtended extends \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler {
    /**
     * make protected historyRecords public available
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getHistoryRecords() {
        return $this->historyRecords;
    }
}

Then I registered the class in ext_localconf.php of my extension (see the wiki link how this works).


Finally, I just called $data->getHistoryRecords() instead of $data->historyRecords in my hook.

That was all, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. I've added a link to the XCLASS documentation to my answer